# How to extract data from dynamic websute ? i am getting empty array when i use this in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

link of the website : https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?zip=60102&distance=50000&entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity=m4

how to extract the name and price of the car ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide your example code which produces said (empty) output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.